# Overcoming "windows can only be installed to gpt disks" while installing windows 8 to new computer

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I bought a new laptop without windows. Now i want to install windows 8. I formatted entire hard disk (file format = NTFS) and then tried to install windows 8. When selecting the disk to install, the following error is displayed:

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. the selected disk has an MBR
> partition table. On EFI system, windows can only be installed to GPT
> disks.

What i can do?

Comment: Windows setup should offer to repartition the disk (maybe under "Advanced" at the drive selection screen).  Let it.

Comment: Instead of MBR use GPT.  You can use GParted to acomplish this.

Comment: @Ramhound, how can do that? in cmd. because i can't go to windows.

Comment: @BenVoigt, there are nothing like that.

Comment: GParted is a Linux tool which you can get any number of ways. As already pointed out. Windows installer itself can also create the partitions for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inside windows installer, hit Shift+F10 to get a command prompt, then run `diskpart` and select the target disk.  Zap the drive (with the `clean` command), create GPT table (`new gpt`), create the GPT-EFI special partitions.

[Step-by-step instructions provided by Microsoft here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297800) (For Windows XP x64, newer versions of `diskpart` such as included in your Windows 8 support all these commands and more)

Then reboot so the firmware finds those partitions and adds the disk to the EFI-native boot order (Windows installer checks this).

Answer (score 54):

As per technet.microsoft.com follow the below steps:

1. Turn off the PC, and put in the Windows installation DVD or USB key.
   Boot the PC to the DVD or USB key in UEFI mode. For more info, see Boot to UEFI
2. Mode or Legacy BIOS mode.
3. From inside Windows Setup, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open a command prompt window. Open the diskpart tool:

   ```
   diskpart
   ```
4. Identify the drive to reformat:

   ```
   list disk
   ```
5. Select the drive, and reformat it:
   *WARNING: The clean command will erase everything on that disk.*

   ```
   select disk <disk number>
   clean
   convert gpt
   exit
   ```
6. Close the command prompt window.
   Continue the Windows Setup installation.
   When choosing an installation type, select **Custom**.
7. The drive will appear as a single area of unallocated space.
8. Select the unallocated space and click Next.
9. Windows begins the installation.

Comment: Much better answer than the accepted one as diskpart is not exactly intuitive to use

Comment: It helped , but please take backup of whole hard driver as clean command will clear your hard drive

Comment: I was helping my friend reinstall windows on the phone and we ran into this. This answer worked flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: The "clean" command is ambiguous. Many users will not understand that, this clean will erase everything

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Jerry saved my life.