# Install Windows after Linux

Tags: linux, windows, linux-mint, mbr, windows-installation

At first i installed Linux mint on my hard drive. This disk is splitted up into two partitions. After i installed linux i formatted the 2nd partition and deleted and created it new. It's the /dev/sda3.
If i try to install windows from an usb stick on it, i cant because it presents me the following error message: 
"windows cannot be installed to this disk. the selected disk has an mbr partition table".

My partitions look like:

```
/dev/sda1            2048   976562175   488280064   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       976564222   982421503     2928641    5  Erweiterte
Partition 2 beginnt nicht an einer physikalischen Sektorgrenze.
/dev/sda3       982421504  2000408575   508993536    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       976564224   982421503     2928640   82  Linux Swap / Solaris
```

So i tried to convert my partition scheme to gpt i did this:
sudo gdisk /dev/sda3

Then i get the following message:

```
Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
***************************************************************

Exact type match not found for type code 7000; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'
Exact type match not found for type code 4300; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'
Exact type match not found for type code 7200; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
2753840503 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility
```

Do i really need to resize my /dev/sda2? But to what should i resize it then? Just make it smaller or what?

Comment: What windows version?

Comment: There are numerous questions on that error.  [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/400449/troubleshooting-windows-cannot-be-installed-to-this-disk-the-selected-disk-has), [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/830470/windows-installation-disk-mbr-error), [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/709254/overcoming-windows-can-only-be-installed-to-gpt-disks-while-installing-windows), and [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/709254/overcoming-windows-can-only-be-installed-to-gpt-disks-while-installing-windows)

Comment: @JanRüegg - What version of Windows does not matter in the context of this question.  The solution is identical across ALL supported versions of Windows including Windows XP.